# How to load default 4 items in a row in my website. Magento 1.7

Tags: javascript, css, js-css

This is the website I'm working https://www.joliefi.com as you can see if you maximize your web browser by default and refresh the homepage you will notice on page load it loads 3 column and later on become 4 column when the whole page is finished loading. I don't know exactly what code to edit, if it's .css or .js. I believe some of the experts here can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you needed the site to be load?

Comment: Load the product display onpage load 4 items per row. because currently it's 3 items per row, and when it's almost finished loading the whole page it automatically adjust to 4 items per row. so there is a delay.

Comment: all your css are minified. i think you can change this css

.products-grid li.item {
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
margin-bottom: 10px;
/* margin-left: 0; */
}

Comment: Try removing unncessary border or padding, I think that is the issue. or check these rules:-

.products-grid li.item {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)
.container_12 .grid_3 {
    width: 308px;
}

Try playing with them

Comment: I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: So it's css not javascript issue?